# async await calling into multiple synchronous methods

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await

I'm wondering how to best handle this async await chain where multiple CPU bound methods need to be called sequentially after the async chain.

I've typed up a small example below.

I'm just trying to find out what the best performing / least side effecting pattern is. I want to make sure I'm not defeating the async benefits. My Filter methods do not access anything that is async and awaitable so to make them async means I would have to return Task.Run(() => Filter1(criterion)) in the calling method or something like await Task.Run(() => { return events; }); in the filter methods themselves. Which way to go for a best practice is the question. This is where most discussions stop so a full example and recommendation would be nice.

Are there any 4.5 async await gurus out there who can give good advice?

```
namespace test
{
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Http;

    public class sampleController : ApiController
    {
        private Service _service;

        public sampleController()
        {
            _service = new Service();
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SomeTask(DiagnosesSearchCriterion criterion)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<Diagnosis>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, await _service.GetDiagnosesByGroup(criterion));
        }
    }

    public class Service
    {
        private Repository _repository;

        public Service()
        {
            _repository = new Repository();
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Diagnosis>> GetDiagnosis(DiagnosesSearchCriterion criterion)
        {
            System.IO.Stream events = await _repository.GetEvents(criterion);

            // Will these block? Should they be async? They are CPU bound... 
            // how to best handle this, they need to be called sequentially in most cases.
            events = Filter1(criterion, events);
            events = Filter2(criterion, events);

            return new Diagnosis[]{};
        }

        public System.IO.Stream Filter1(DiagnosesSearchCriterion criterion, System.IO.Stream events)
        {
            // CPU bound PLINQ and Parallel filtering logic here.....

            return events;
        }

        public System.IO.Stream Filter2(DiagnosesSearchCriterion criterion, System.IO.Stream events)
        {
            // CPU bound PLINQ and Parallel filtering logic here.....
            // ....

            return events;
        }
    }

    public class Repository
    {
        public async Task<System.IO.Stream> GetEvents(DiagnosesSearchCriterion criterion)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            return await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync("http://www.blah.com/stuff");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Filter1 and Filter2 will block, yes. I'm not entirely sure what your question is -- could you reword it?

Comment: Yes, you should have `Filter1` and `Filter2` be "async" if they are CPU bound because the code after the `await` will be invoked on the main thread (which will be the UI thread in Winform/WPF application)

Comment: Cory. I'm just trying to find out what the best performing / least side effecting pattern is. I want to make sure I'm not defeating the async benefits.  My Filter methods do not access anything that is async and awaitable so to make them async means I would have to return Task.Run(() => Filter1(criterion)) in the calling method or something like await Task.Run<Stream>(() => { return events; }); in the filter methods themselves. Which way to go for a best practice is the question.  This is where most discussions stop so a full example and recommendation would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, your primary benefit from `async` is *scalability* - that is, the thread pool thread is freed up from handling a request if the request is just waiting for some I/O to complete.

In this case (where your methods are CPU-bound), there's no benefit from making them `async`. You'll still be taking up a thread pool thread (and adding a small amount of overhead) by using `Task.Run`. Since they should be executed sequentially, the easiest way to do this is to invoke them synchronously, just like your code is currently doing.

I think this scenario is addressed in the excellent [Async in ASP.NET video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET). Note that this same situation on the client side would be handled differently. On the client side, your primary benefit from `async` is *responsiveness*, so it *would* make sense to toss CPU work into a thread pool thread (`Task.Run`), since that would free up the UI thread.

(As a side note, it's usually not a good idea to do parallel processing on a server, unless you're sure your user count will be quite low).

Comment: Thank you Stephen for the excellent advice which I was able to verify with the link you sent along with this one. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/02/08/9960003.aspx